# parse iostat output using awk

Tags: awk, aix, iostat

I'm trying to filter the output of the parameter **avgserv** from the **read** line, using awk.

The default output of my iostat command: `iostat -D hdisk0` is as follow:

```
bash-4.4$ iostat -D hdisk0

System configuration: lcpu=32 drives=9 paths=126 vdisks=0

hdisk0          xfer:  %tm_act      bps      tps      bread      bwrtn
                          0.0      3.0K     0.1       98.3        2.9K
                read:      rps  avgserv  minserv  maxserv   timeouts      fails
                          0.0      0.8      0.0      0.0           0          0
               write:      wps  avgserv  minserv  maxserv   timeouts      fails
                          0.1      2.2      0.0      0.0           0          0
               queue:  avgtime  mintime  maxtime  avgwqsz    avgsqsz     sqfull
                          0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0        0.0         0.0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using: `iostat -D hdisk0 | awk '/avgserv/'`
I've managed to print the lines which matches: **avgserv**

```
bash-4.4$ iostat -D hdisk0 | awk '/avgserv/'
                read:      rps  avgserv  minserv  maxserv   timeouts      fails
               write:      wps  avgserv  minserv  maxserv   timeouts      fails
```

But,

First, i'm only returning the Headers, without the Actual Values.

Second, 
I need to return the **avgserv** parameter, only for the **read** line. Not for the write line.

My finale output should containe only the value of **avgserv** parameter, and only for the **read** line:

> 0.8

After a some digging,
I've managed to return only the **avgserv** parameter using: `iostat -D hdisk0 | awk '/avgserv/ {print  $3}'`

But still,
I'm getting the required parameter for Both lines (read and write), and again without the actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
your_command | 
awk '
/avgserv/ && /read/{
  found=1
  next
}
found{
  print $2
  found=""
}'
```

***One liner form of solution:***

```
your_command | awk '/avgserv/ && /read/{found=1;next} found{print $2;found=""}'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
your_command |              ##Sending your command output as standard input to awk command.
awk '                       ##Starting awk command from here.
/avgserv/ && /read/{        ##Checking condition if a line has string avgserv AND read then do following.
  found=1                   ##Setting variable found value to 1 here.
  next                      ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                           ##Closing BLOCK for above condition here.
found{                      ##Checking condition if found is NOT NULL then do following.
  print $2                  ##Printing 2nd field here.
  found=""                  ##Nullifying variable found here.
}'                          ##Closing BLOCK for found condition here.
```

Comment: can you please explain your code? is there an option for a one liner command?

Comment: @edwio, Explanation added already in my solution :) Sure lemme add one-liner form now.

Comment: @edwio, I have added one liner form of solution too now, kindly do lemme know in case of any queries here.

Comment: Why do we need to use found=""  (Nullifying variable found here)? we already printing the value of the 2nd field

Comment: @edwio, that is because it should NOT print anything(any line) other than next line of `avgserv` and `read`, else once it is `1` and NOT cleared later then it may print not needed results too, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Short capturing from the *opposite side*:

```
$ iostat -D hdisk0 | awk '/write: +.*avgserv/{ print v; exit }{ v=$2 }'
0.8
```

Comment: can you please elaborate what did you mean by the opposite?